# Why is the debian installer an exe file

Tags: linux, windows, installation

I recently downloaded the debian installer iso to use with virtualbox. For security reasons, I mounted it to ensure it was legit. I noticed a file labeled setup.exe. Why would a linux installer be a windows file, and how would the computer be able to run it?

I then decided to look throught the microsoft windows installer. It too used an exe file. How could it run the exe to install windows without windows instlled?

Comment: Its probably one of the many installers that come in the installation disk, this one is the one to be ran on Windows. There are probably others for other systems, and of course theres the installer you would expect to find there, the one that is in the disk's boot sector, its not even a file that you can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The Debian project has an [installer](https://wiki.debian.org/LennyIllustratedInstall) for Microsoft Windows that provides a UI for installing GNU/Linux beginning on a MS Windows platform.
2. The Windows kernel can be loaded from disk and once it is loaded, like on install, it can start running a .exe file. For similar reasons Linux is an elf format binary. This is how a "Live" disk works, it loads the kernel and then loads up the entire OS including window manager from disk.

Answer (score 0):

To your first question :
I bet you are running VirtualBox on a Windows client right? So there is nothing wrong with using a windows file :)

Comment: OK, but why is the microsoft windows installer an exe? Windows would have to run the file...

Comment: @anonymousanonymous: Windows *does* run the file.  Specifically, the cut-down version of Windows on the install DVD runs it.

Comment: @anonymousanonymous : It´s like the chicken-and-egg problem. You need to run an .exe for starting windows but you need windows to run the .exe :) It is solved in a kind of an live-system. If you insert a windows cd, there is already everything on the cd you need to run an .exe. The .iso you use for VirtualBox is nothing different then such an cd.